# How to loop use jinja2 for loop to create a select element?

Tags: jinja2

Say I have a python list called seq and I want to render it in a select element how do I do that?

I tried:

```
<select name="Exercise1">
         {% for item in seq %}
            <option  value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
         {% endfor %}
         </select>
```

it didn't work.

UPDATE:
here is the template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Unit 2 Rot 13</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Enter some text to ROT13:</h2>
    <form method="post">

                 <select name="Exercise1">
              {% for item in seq %}
                <option  value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
             {% endfor %}
             </select>


      <br>
      <input type="submit">

    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

and here is the rendered html source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Unit 2 Rot 13</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Enter some text to ROT13:</h2>
    <form method="post">

                 <select name="Exercise1">

                  </select>


      <br>
      <input type="submit">

    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure why the element just disappears and there is no errors raised.

Comment: In what way did it "not work"? Your template looks fine (assuming everything is already escaped properly).

Comment: well, the select element is not appearing in the rendered html.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `seq` contains? And if you put a dummy link right above the select, and another right below, do they show up?

Comment: seq=['1','2','3','4']
Yes the element above it and under it appears normally.

Comment: I added an update to the question,

Comment: @camarara: Looks like `seq` is empty (or undefined). Are you sure it's being injected properly into the template context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are very close my friend you just missed a few spaces:

You wrote this:

```
<option  value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
```

Which needs to look like this:

```
<option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
```

Let me know if that fixes it. Good luck!

Without those spaces it just looks like garbage to python and to the browser :)

Comment: mine does not work (it works allright when I substitute variables with strings, though)      <select>
        {% for t in templates %}
            <option value="{{ t.id }}">{{ t.title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

Answer (score 0):

Check the function where you render template, it must contain:

```
def generate_template_for_exercize1():

    seq = [1, 2, 3] #here you probably will have more complex statement

    return render_template('your_template.html', seq=seq)
```